# Coinbase currency_exchange error

Tags: php, jquery, json, bitcoin, coinbase-api

Accessing the coinbase API https://coinbase.com/api/doc/1.0/currencies/exchange_rates.html
In my case i have text boxes with Bitcoin field and other currencies field(usd,gbp,eur etc..)
What i tried is

```
 <h6>BTC</h6>
 <input type="text" id ="coin"/>
 <div class="row">
    <h6>USD</h6>
    <input type="text" id='usd'/>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
    <h6>GBP</h6>
    <input type="text" id="gbp"/>
 </div>
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#coin').keyup(function () {
        var url = 'https://coinbase.com/api/v1/currencies/exchange_rates?callback=?';
        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        });
    });
});
```

**Error**

SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

```
{"vnd_to_usd":"4.7e-05","ars_to_btc":"0.00021","mmk_to_btc":"2.0e-06","ye..
```

what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: sounds like they have a problem with jsonp.

Comment: you would have to talk with them.

Comment: The syntax error is likely a problem with **your** code rather than coinbase's API. coinbase doesn't support JSONP, nor do they support CORS. This means your options of using this API within a browser is 0. You're going to have to communicate with a PHP page on your domain, then that PHP page will have to proxy requests to coinbase.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for your comments i fixed this.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#coin').keyup(function () {           
         var btc = $('#coin').val();
         $.ajax({
              url: "<?php echo site_url("buy/exchange_rates"); ?>",
              type: "POST",
              data: {
                 btc:btc
              },
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                $('#usd').val(data.usd);
                $('#gbp').val(data.gbp);
              },
              async: false,
              error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              }
           });
        }); 



 function exchange_rates()
    {
    $btc = $this->input->post('btc');
    if ($btc != "")
        {
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://coinbase.com/api/v1/currencies/exchange_rates"), 'TRUE');
        $usd = round($data['btc_to_usd']);
        $gbp = round($data['btc_to_gbp']);
        $obj = array();
        $obj['usd'] = $usd; 
        $obj['gbp'] = $gbp;  
        echo json_encode($obj);
        }
    }
```